# Change primary key from "id" to "any_other_key"

Tags: rethinkdb, feathersjs, feathers-service

How can I change primary key of **RethinkDB** after my rethinkdb feathers service is created?

I tried below code but it won't affect.

```
app.use('/messages', service({
  id: 'user_id',
  Model: db,
  name: 'messages'
}));
```

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0):

When using a different primary key the RethinkDB database needs to be initialized with the same `primaryKey` option. You can either do that manually or use `service.init` as [documented here](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-rethinkdb#adapterinitoptions):

```
// Initialize the `messages` table with `user_id` as the primary key
app.service('messages').init({
  primaryKey: 'user_id'
}).then(() => {
  // Use service here
});
```

Comment: Tried this also but not getting a proper result.